# Spring roo label in show.jsxp and list.jspx

Tags: java, jsp, spring-roo

I'm new to Spring roo and working on my first application. I read the "Spring Roo in action" but one question I do not got answered.

I have a one-to-many relationship.
When listing the many table/object I want to show one field from the related parent. Now I get all fields of the parent concatenated.

I already figured out that in the **create.jspx** and **update.jspx** views one can use the itemLabel="fieldName" notation and this works fine.

But what is the equivalent for the show.jspx and list.jspx views?

Answer (score 1):

You get all fields of parent because jspx is using the `toString` method of the parent to transform object to a String value.

The easy and faster way to solve this is *push-in* the `toString` method form the *.aj* file to *.java* and customize the return of this method. Spring Roo when found the method on *.java* file will not generate it again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I knew I could use the the toString method. But my problem with that is that I can only define toString one time. Certainly during development it is handy to have the current toString implementation and see all the field.
Is there another way

Answer (score 1):

Probably the toString() method worked in the past, but in the 1.3.1 version this does not solve the problem, at least for the jspx views, see [Chapter 11. Web MVC Add-On](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html), see 11.2. Application Conversion Service.

Instead you have to "push-in" the **.getToStringConverter()** methods in the ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj to ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.java

and customize it as you like.